# How to use RSpec to test if the category of an item is a valid category in the category table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, associations

I have a item model of which each item should have one category which is a valid category.

in my item.rb, I have

has_one :category

and in my category.rb, I have

belongs_to :item

is that right? and how do I validate that my item has a valid category using RSpec?

Please help and Thanks!

Comment: What's a valid category in your case? Also your item and category has a one-to-one relationship? I'd think normally a category can have many items and an item can belong to one or more categories.

Comment: you are right, it should have been has_many :category instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have two tests:

```
let(:valid_category) { stub_model(Category, :valid? => true) }
let(:invalid_category) { stub_model(Category, :valid? => false) }

let(:params) { {} } # valid parameters except category

specify { Item.new(params.merge(:category => valid_category)).should be_valid }
specify { Item.new(params.merge(:category => invalid_category)).should_not be_valid }
```